# Screenshotting Linux VM in Mac

Tags: linux, macos, kali-linux, vmware-fusion

I am running VMware fusion on my Macbook Pro to run a Kali Linux VM. The OS for my Macbook is Mojave.

Whenever I am in my VM and try to take a screenshot of a window , usually being my terminal (Command+Shift+4), the window distorts and moves out of the cross hairs of my screen capture, making it nearly impossible to get a good screen shot. This is incredibly frustrating.

A colleague of mine said he has the exact same issue. Has anybody seen this before and found a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grab. An application that comes with the system software. Grab allows you to capture the screen, a window, or a selected area. Grab is located in /Application/Utilities

Comment: Thanks but would really rather find a workaround for using command+shift+4. If i had to guess, it is in the vmware fusion config settings